# If we know information existed when life first began on earth, then can’t we surmise that information existed prior to earth life?

Tags: conservation-laws, information, biology

If true, then wouldn’t information have been created when the universe was created?

In other words, if information existed from the start of the universe, then it’s possible that information can not be created or destroyed, it’s just converted from disordered information to ordered information, using energy(?).

Comment: As far as we know quite a lot of universe existed before life on earth formed, does this not count as information?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Information is a mathematical abstraction. Life is a phenomenon that (so far) resists description via mathematical abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what you mean by information here. In physics, information is often used to refer to the number of possible states of a system, similar to Shannon entropy.

Under most definitions of information, it has always been a fundamental part of the universe. In a more philosophical sense, some physicists would say that the universe is made of, or equivalent to, information.